# How to open a mobile version website using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following code to open the mobile version of Facebook in Firefox in my Desktop by changing the user-agent.

```
@Test
public void fb() {
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
        ffprofile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "iPhone"); //this will change the user agent which will open mobile browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(400,800)); //just to change the window size so that it will look like mobile ;)
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("************");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    }
```

But for some reason, it doesn't seem to work quite right. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If it's about mobile, why you aren't using appium?

Comment: @Emna - Sorry if this question sounds stupid to you as I don't know much about appium. Do we need an actual mobile device in order to test using appium?

Comment: You can use a simulator, not only real device. Both are ok with appium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try sending a request to http://m.facebook.com, this is facebooks mobile website, This will only work if its just for facebook though.